# RMSprop, Adam, AdaDelta test accuracy does not improve using Caffe

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am `finetuning` using `Caffe` on an image dataset on a `Tesla K40`. Using a `batch size=47`, `solver_type=SGD`, `base_lr=0.001`, `lr_policy="step"`, `momentum=0.9`, `gamma=0.1`, the `training loss` decreases and `test accuracy` goes from `2%-50%` in `100` iterations which is quite good.

When using other optimisers such as `RMSPROP`, `ADAM` and `ADADELTA`, the `training loss` remains almost the same even and no improvement in `test accuracy` after `1000` iterations.

For `RMSPROP`, I have changed the respective parameters as mentioned [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_solver_rmsprop.prototxt).

For `ADAM`, I have changed the respective parameters as mentioned [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_solver_adam.prototxt)

For `ADADELTA`, I have changed the respective parameters as mentioned [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_adadelta_solver.prototxt)

Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I've found that one should use lower learning rates with solvers different from SGD. Howeber, I don't quite know why.

Comment: How much do you lower the learning rate, compared to SGD?

Comment: If I use the same learning rate as with SGD the RMSProp algorithm diverges, whereas it will converge (with a slightly lower acc than my well-tuned SGD) with a learning rate that is 1/3 of the original. However, it might be very problem-specific.

Comment: @VeilEclipse: Do you solve your issue? I aslo met the issue. I used Adam/without Adam give same result. I am using `base_lr` same with SGD

Answer (score 2):

I saw similar results to pir: Adam would diverge when given the same base_lr that SGD used.  When I reduced base_lr to 1/100 of its original value, Adam suddenly converged, and gave good results.

Comment: Thanks for your point out. It means if `base_lr`: 1e-3 for SGD then `base_lr: 1e-5` for Adam. Is it too small?

Comment: I have found that 1e-4 is a good learning rate for Adam.  You should also try 1e-3 and 1e-5 on your data set to see if you get good performance

Comment: In my case, lr_rate for Adam is twice time than SGD. I also tried 50%, 150% , but 200% lr_rate is best for me