# solver.prototxt for adam solver in caffe

Tags: caffe, solver, gradient-descent

My solver.prototxt using adam is as follows. Do I need to add or remove any terms? The loss doesnt seem to reduce

```
net: "/home/softwares/caffe-master/examples/hpm/hp.prototxt"
test_iter: 6
test_interval: 1000
base_lr: 0.001
momentum: 0.9
momentum2: 0.999
delta: 0.00000001
lr_policy: "fixed"
regularization_type: "L2"
stepsize: 2000
display: 100
max_iter: 20000
snapshot: 1000

snapshot_prefix: "/home/softwares/caffe-master/examples/hpm/hp"
type: "Adam"
solver_mode: GPU
```

Answer (score 1):

By comparing with [caffe example on mnist](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_solver_adam.prototxt), 'stepsize' can be deleted since 'lr_policy' is 'fixed'.

Comment: it may be correct, but I don't think this is why the loss does not converge

Comment: Yes, I agree. One suggestion is to change 'base_lr'. Maybe the other question is relevant: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36440449/7709837).

Answer (score 1):

How about your work? If you used Adam. I suggest you look at the setting in caffe. I do not know why you have L2 and delta value. [This](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/mnist/lenet_solver_adam.prototxt) is standard setting

```
# The train/test net protocol buffer definition
# this follows "ADAM: A METHOD FOR STOCHASTIC OPTIMIZATION"
net: "examples/mnist/lenet_train_test.prototxt"
# test_iter specifies how many forward passes the test should carry out.
# In the case of MNIST, we have test batch size 100 and 100 test iterations,
# covering the full 10,000 testing images.
test_iter: 100
# Carry out testing every 500 training iterations.
test_interval: 500
# All parameters are from the cited paper above
base_lr: 0.001
momentum: 0.9
momentum2: 0.999
# since Adam dynamically changes the learning rate, we set the base learning
# rate to a fixed value
lr_policy: "fixed"
# Display every 100 iterations
display: 100
# The maximum number of iterations
max_iter: 10000
# snapshot intermediate results
snapshot: 5000
snapshot_prefix: "examples/mnist/lenet"
# solver mode: CPU or GPU
type: "Adam"
solver_mode: GPU
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a learning rate of 0.1 and a slower step size like 300 and watch the behavior, also check if the lmdb/hdf5 file is well formed and have a correct scale to ease the learning, you can do this by generating the mean file over your dataset.